# Como gerar Math.random partindo de um valor diferente de 0?

Tags: javascript, random, matemática

Opa pessoal, acabei de conhecer o metodo Math.random e já sei como gerar valores partindo de 0   até um outro numero através de multiplicação, ex: Math.random()*20.

Mas tô matutando como eu posso fazer a mesma coisa sendo que partindo por exemplo de 5 até 20, já varri a net e ninguém explica :/

Agradeço desde já quem puder me ajudar!

Comment: veja minha resposta com uma função auxiliar que pode servir para você.

Answer (score 2):

O [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) é por defenição um numero entre `0` e `1`. O que você pode fazer é adicionar o valor que quer para ter o resultado que quer. Ou seja:

```
var numeroAleatorio = 5 + (Math.random() * 15);
```

Assim garante que o resultado possivel inferior é `5`, e o possível superior é `20`.

Ou seja o `5` neste caso muda o minimo que esse código pode dar, e o 15 neste caso, somado com o minimo, será o máximo que o código pode dar.

Comment: Obrigado Sergio. Mas como faz para não passar de 20?

Comment: @ropbla9 sendo que o numeto máximo que o `Math.round()` dá é `1` então o numero máximo dessa linha que coloquei é `20`. OU seja `5 + (1 * 15)`

Comment: E se eu quisesse sortear apenas de 5 a 15?

Comment: Se quiser de `5` a `15` pode fazer `var numeroAleatorio = 5 + (Math.random() * 10);`

Comment: Puts, sem palavras. Muito obrigado! A preguiça de pensar aqui tá demais, to capengando de sono mas só vou dormir quando termino minhas anotações :/

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar as seguintes funções:

Returna um número aleatório entre o min (inclusivo) e max (exclusivo):

```
function getNumeroRandom(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

Returna um número aleatório entre o min (inclusivo) e max (inclusivo):

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

> obs: Utilizando Math.round () lhe dará uma distribuição não uniforme, mas com a função getRandomInt() você tem uma distribuição perfeitamente uniforme.

Comment: Obrigado man pelo método! É mais um no meu leque. Entretanto o método do Sérgio acima da o mesmo efeito e é bem mais prático! Ou você discorda?

Comment: @ropbla9 daria no mesmo é feito sim.. mas que tem uma função com parâmetros, você pode setar eles quando chamar-la passando os valores min e max(de forma "dinâmica")... já o outro método os valores são estáticos e tem que ficar mudando eles quando você quiser fazer o sorteio entre os dois números.

Comment: Pedro, mas com aquele metodo eu tambem posso setar o 1 +  e o *19 como parâmetros de forma que eles fiquem dinamicos da mesma forma.

Ou não?

Comment: @ropbla9 pode sim.. mas você vai estar alterando pra somente um caso especifico ... e com função você atende todos os casos, porque fica algo mais generalizado.

Comment: @ropbla9 uma coisa é criar uma variável.. e outra e uma função que é algo geral que pode ser usado mais de uma vez independentemente dos valores evitando a duplicação..

Comment: O ponto em se ter uma função é evitar a duplicação e diminuir a chance de erro!

Comment: @renatoargh justamante isso aew.

Comment: Mas da mesma forma eu posso encaixar 1+ e 19* como parametros de uma função, ué